# What does this Selenium error mean?

Tags: selenium

Using Selenium to control a FireFox browser instance. It works but it throws off a boatload of error messages and this is one of them:

```
WARNING: pipe error: 109: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w32-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
```

Comment: There is warnings and can be ignored

Comment: What versions are you using?

Comment: Versions of what?